# Sed script match condition fails at the end of file

Tags: sed

I'm using the following script to make `ip addr` print one line per interface:

```
ip addr | sed -nr '/^\w+: /{
    H
    :top
    n
    /^\s/ { H ; b top }
    x
    s/\n//g
    a \ ==========
    p
    b top
  }
'
```

Input:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1600 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:33:58:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe33:58cb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:33:58:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.10/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe33:58ca/64 scope link
```

Output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo    inet6 ::1/128 scope host        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 ==========
2: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1600 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000    link/ether 08:00:27:33:58:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe33:58cb/64 scope link        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 ==========
```

The bug: the last interface is always missing. How do fix it?

Comment: You might have better luck using the `ip -o addr` output which prefixes each line with the interface information. (Why that isn't at all what the documentation says it should be is a different issue though. And I just noticed that apparently that output changes in more recent versions of `ip` to not include the link information so bleh.)

Comment: -o produces several lines per interface (at least on CentOS 6) with each line prefixed with the interface name - very strange format which will require additional processing. I thought it's better all be done using one tool.

Comment: Yes, the `-o` output is odd. But it does simplify processing in some senses. You need to process the output anyway. The question is just how you process it. What are you planning to do with the output from this sed command?

Comment: I select only specific fields and print a table of interfaces

Comment: Using some other tool? How?

Answer (score 3):

Good grief, just use `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n\s+/," ")}1' file
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1600 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000 link/ether 08:00:27:33:58:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe33:58cb/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000 link/ether 08:00:27:33:58:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 192.168.122.10/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global eth0 inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe33:58ca/64 scope link
```

`sed` is for simple substitutions on individual lines, it is NOT for anything involving multiple lines. All of seds arcane constructs to do things spanning multiple lines became obsolete in the mid-1970s when `awk` was invented. People only use them today for the mental exercise of seeing if they can solve the puzzle with sed - you would not actually use the resulting incantation in your code.

Change `\s` to `[[:space:]]` above if your awk doesn't support `\s` (`gawk`does).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed $'/^\S/{$h;:a;x;/./{s/\\n//g;p;a\ ==========\n};x;h;d};H;$!d;ba' file
```

As already stated the `n` command on encoutering the end-of-file will terminate the sed commands, so end-of-file must be checked before trying to read in another line.

This sed solution uses the hold space to gather up the record and encountering a new record or the end-of-file, the hold space is swapped for the pattern space, the newlines removed and the extra divider line added.

The use of the bash variable `$'...'` allows the sed commands to be grouped together in  a one line solution, however another way to do this is to use the `-e` flag:

```
sed -e '/^\S/{$h:a;x;/./{s/\n//g;p;a\ ==========' -e '};x;h;d};H;$!d;ba' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the behavior of `n`.

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands):

> n
>
> If auto-print is not disabled, print the pattern space, then, regardless, replace the pattern space with the next line of input. If there is no more input then sed exits without processing any more commands.

So you don't get a chance to do anything with the last field because sed exits on you too early. This seems like very odd behavior for `n` to have to me but that's what it is.

You could do this with `awk` easily enough:

```
ip addr show | awk '/^\w+: / {
        if (iface) {print iface}
        iface=$0
        next
    }
    {iface=iface OFS $0}
    END {print iface}'
```

But depending on what you need to do next it might be just as easy to do all the processing in `awk` directly.

Comment: wrt `if auto-print is not disabled` - couldn't they say `if auto-print is enabled` and spare us the double negative? Even the man pages are convoluted....